# I am trying to echo the changed name on the console.. but the program quits as in when I enter the new name

Tags: node.js, botframework

I am using the textbot to echo the name the user enters and added an option to change the name of user using `set name` command, but the program only takes the new name and won't print it. Wondering what's wrong?

Here's my code

```
var builder = require('botbuilder');

var helloBot = new builder.TextBot();
helloBot.add('/', new builder.CommandDialog()
        .matches('^set name', builder.DialogAction.beginDialog('/profile'))
        .matches('^quit', builder.DialogAction.endDialog())
        .onDefault([
            function (session, args, next) {
                if (!session.userData.name) {
                    session.beginDialog('/profile');
                } else {
                    console.log('in else part..');
                    next();
                }
            },
            function (session, results) {
                session.send('Hello %s!', session.userData.name);
            }
            ]));
helloBot.add('/profile',  [
        function (session) {
            if (session.userData.name) {
                builder.Prompts.text(session, 'What would you like to change it to?');
                console.log('setting name..');
            } else {
                builder.Prompts.text(session, 'Hi! What is your name?');
            }
        },
        function (session, results) {
            session.userData.name = results.response;
            session.endDialog();
        }
        ]);

helloBot.listenStdin();
```

The output should be something like:

```
Hi
Hi! What is your name?
james
Hello james!
set name
What would you like to change it to?
Bond
```

The program quits here while the expected output is 
Hello Bond!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that .onDefault is never called because the root dialog matched the "set name" condition.

Try this code (uses updated version of BotBuilder):

```
var builder = require('botbuilder');

var connector = new builder.ConsoleConnector().listen();
var bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector);
var intents = new builder.IntentDialog();
bot.dialog('/', intents);

intents.matches(/^set name/i, [
    function (session) {
        session.beginDialog('/profile');
    },
    function (session, results) {
        session.send('Hello %s!', session.userData.name);
    }
]);

intents.onDefault([
    function (session, args, next) {
        if (!session.userData.name) {
            session.beginDialog('/profile');
        } else {
            next();
        }
    },
    function (session, results) {
        session.send('Hello %s!', session.userData.name);
    }
]);

bot.dialog('/profile', [
    function (session) {
        if (session.userData.name) {
            builder.Prompts.text(session, 'What would you like to change it to?');
        } else {
            builder.Prompts.text(session, 'Hi! What is your name?');
        }
    },
    function (session, results) {
        session.userData.name = results.response;
        session.endDialog();
    }
]);
```